# Google Analytics 4 not receiving purchase values from Magento 2

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Magento 2.4.5p1.

I have set up Google Analytics 4 via Google Tag Manager and implemented Google Tags.

Connection is there, visits and number of purchases are being measured. But value of purchases is not measured.

Would this here be the correct setting to measure purchase values in the respective currency in the E-Commerce purchase section?

Any hint much appreciated.

[image: setting G4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is Google Tag Manager with a commerce datalayer implementation. This is only available in Magento enterprise (or Adobe Commerce whatever you call it).

I suggest that you install Yireo's implementation of GTM.

https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_GoogleTagManager2/tree/master

(Other modules are also available)

In contrary to the Magento Open Source's implementation, this GTM module adds e-commerce specific data & events in the datalayer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check "Google Signals" data collection is being enabled (located in Admin > Property column > Data settings > Data Collection).

Guide: [[GA4] Activate Google signals for Google Analytics 4 properties](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9445345?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

Google Signals is a feature in Google Analytics 4 that collects additional data about website visitors, such as demographics, based on their Google accounts.

Enabling Google Signals enriches your reports with demographic information and helps identify website visitors. However, it can cause data thresholding, where rows with small numbers are hidden in reports (including purchase events as I know).
[[GA4] Data thresholds](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630?hl=en&sjid=12194931450412064067-AP)

If the client doesn't need demographic data or retargeting with Google Analytics audiences should disable Google Signals to avoid thresholding and maintain accurate reporting.

Another way: Switching to device-based reporting identity can also unlock hidden rows with small numbers but sacrifice user accuracy.

you can see more explanation in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZUvxKQGfuA

[image]

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for that. Unfortunately that did not help. I think it has more to do with the correct set up of data streams and enhanced events.